# Double BJT circuit with one BJT off and one in saturation

Tags: transistors, bjt, saturation, homework

In the circuit below, due to the base voltage, the circuit becomes a common-emitter setup. However, assuming a reasonable value for the base current the BJT should be in saturation.

[image]

However the value given for β is a βmin value (βmin = 30), which only holds for active forward mode. I attempted to calculate the βforced value by assuming an Isc/Is value of 100, which yielded βforced = 14.45. However using this value with KVL from B to E gives 10 - 10000ib - 0.7 - 1000(βforced + 1)ib = 0 yields an ib value of 0.365 mA and an ic value of 5.3 mA, which is different from the value of ic given in the book (4.35 mA).

What am I doing wrong here? It seems like it should be a straightforward question but I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overthinking this.

The emitter current is 4.8mA using your 200mV drop for a transistor in saturation. The emitter voltage is 4.8V.

The base current is (10V-(4.8V+0.7V))/10K =  450uA

The sum of all three currents flowing into the transistor must be ??